# OpenCV MinEnclosingCircle algorithm

Tags: algorithm, opencv

I'm searching for the algorithm is used in Opencv function minEnclosingCircle. The only thing I could find in the documentation of [opencv](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga8ce13c24081bbc7151e9326f412190f1) is that they use a iterative algorithm. 
Best regards

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp

Answer (score 1):

Remember that OpenCV is opensource. This means you can look at the source code and check the implementation.

You can find [in the implementation](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp#L206) that:

```
// see Welzl, Emo. Smallest enclosing disks (balls and ellipsoids). Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 1991.
void cv::minEnclosingCircle( InputArray _points, Point2f& _center, float& _radius ) { ... }
```

So you're looking for the algorithm described in the article:

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{Welzl91smallestenclosing, 
author = {Emo Welzl},
title = {Smallest Enclosing Disks (balls and Ellipsoids)},
booktitle = {Results and New Trends in Computer Science},
year = {1991},
pages = {359--370},
publisher = {Springer-Verlag}
}
```

You can find a pdf version [here](https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/emo/PublFiles/SmallEnclDisk_LNCS555_91.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very,very much. I had already searched in the sources (in Github), but I did not find the correct file.